# How to highlight the filtered contents based on the input search value and not on alphabet click using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

i have list of items, based on search it is highlighting the alphabets which i am searching for. Now, i want the alphabets to get highlighted if i am using input search box, but it also highlights if i select any alphabet from the alphabet row.

Demo:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ku9aaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmedical-offices.ts)

TS:

```
   searchFacility(search) {
    this.sLetter = search;
    let memberFacilities = true;
    if (search) {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = this.dtFacilities.value;
        this.dtFacilities.value.forEach(m => {
          m.memberFacilities.forEach(f => {
            let mySearch = search.toLowerCase();
            let facilityName = f.facilityName.toLowerCase();
            if (facilityName && facilityName.includes(mySearch)) {
              f.isShowMember = false;
              memberFacilities = false;
            } else {
              f.isShowMember = true;
            }
          })
        })
        if (memberFacilities) {
          this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
        }
      }, 100);

    }
    else {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      this.dtFacilities.value.forEach(m => {
        m.memberFacilities.map(f => {
          f.isShowMember = false;
        })
      })
    }
    if(search==''){
      this.searchFname="";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve can be solved by putting a `sLetter.toUppedCase()`:

```
 <a (click)="searchFacility(alphabet)" [class.activeletter]="sLetter.toUpperCase()===alphabet"> {{alphabet}}</a>
```

I also added a class for the activeletter:

```
.activeletter {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

I forked it here to check how it works:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55804980-letterhighlight?file=src/app/app.component.css

**Update:**

After your comment I saw the code another time. There is a little mess between the `sLetter` and the search value `searchFname`. You should clarify what one do you want to use to filter (probably `searchFname`).
Also don't override the `sLetter` on every search and update the pipe `getHtml` to accept the starting letter and the searchText.

**Check the updated stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55804980-letterhighlight2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, what i meant to explain is, if i click on "A" then i get the filtered list, so in the list if "a/A" is there it is highlighted with yellow color, so i want that color highlighting to the filtered list only if i give in input search box, but not with the "A" click

Comment: I dont want, the alphabet to show in input search box, when i click on alphabets, how can this be changed?

Comment: Then you have to update the `searchMedicalOffices` pipe too and change  the method  `getAlph`  I updated the code. I hope that's what you need.  Anyway, I think you shouldn't use a pipe to do the search, that makes everything much harder to follow and a little confusing when you only want the value of the search (and slower, much slower).

Comment: Please update the answer, in answer along with Demo, so that it helps others as well. Thanks a lot, i voted and accepted your answer

Comment: Hi, i have one issue in this, if i give search by input box, and i click on All, then it shows the child values

Comment: For example, now type "che" in search box and it shows the filtered list, now click on "All" it must hide all child elements as it does with the Alphabet search and click on "ALL"

Comment: That's because `dtFacilities.value` is changing with the **PIPE** , That's another of the a lot of reasons that I don't recommend using pipes to get values. If you see you "solved" (I think that there are better solutions)  this with a `timeout` before. Check the stackblitz another time. I strongly suggest you making the code much easier removing that pipes and making that calls as normal functions.

Comment: ya this is what i wanted, il check in my application

Answer (score 0):

remove the click event on alphabets, change

```
  <a (click)="searchFacility(alphabet)" [class.activeletter]="sLetter==alphabet"> {{alphabet}}</a>
```

to

```
  <a   [class.activeletter]="sLetter==alphabet"> {{alphabet}}</a>
```

Comment: thanks for response, but i need to filter the contents, if i remove that click event then filtering doesnt happen